# How Do I Open Text by Clicking on An Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am making my first website and I am trying to be able to have someone click an image and then it open text to explain what that image is/does.

I would also like it to dim the background and allow the user to click outside the text popup to close.

I feel like I am very close, but I could use some help.

Any advice is appreciated!

Thank you!

- Jordan

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */

}

}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
#caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a Corona Bottle</h2>
<p>I enjoy Corona!</p>

<img id="myImg" src="http://thebearbrewpub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Corona.jpg" alt="Corona Bottle" width="300" height="200">


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
$('#myImg').on('click', function(){
$('#myImg').css("opacity", "0");
})

$('#closeTextBoxID').on('click', function(){
$('#myImg').css("opacity", "1");
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain the problem you are having.  What's not working?  Any error messages?

Comment: When I click the image, it opens the image in a larger window. I just want to have text open up that explains what the image is.

Comment: @dotJPEG, the text you are adding is showing up but its the same color as the background. Add `color: white;` to the `myModal` css.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for that edit, but now I would like the image to go away and just have the text

Comment: @dotJPEG remove `<img class="modal-content" id="img01">` and `var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");` and `modalImg.src = this.src;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    color: white;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */

}

}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
#caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a Corona Bottle</h2>
<p>I enjoy Corona!</p>

<img id="myImg" src="http://thebearbrewpub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Corona.jpg" alt="Corona Bottle" width="300" height="200">


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
$('#myImg').on('click', function(){
$('#myImg').css("opacity", "0");
})

$('#closeTextBoxID').on('click', function(){
$('#myImg').css("opacity", "1");
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you!